# Which of the following is/are correct? Related to Limits, Differentiability, Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Which of the following is/are correct?

$(A)$ **If a function is differentiable then its derivative is a continuous function.**

I couldn't find any example which makes derivative, not continuous. So I need help here.

$(B)$ **If LHD and RHD does not exist finitely at $x=a$ function is discontinuous at $x=a$**

Taking the example of $y=|x|$ it is not differentiable at $x=0$ but is continuous. So this option is incorrect.

So Differentiability $\rightarrow $Continuity but (Not Differentiability) $\nrightarrow$ (Not Continuity )?

$(C)$ **Every function which is defined for all $x$  can be thought of as a derivative of some function.**
**$(D)$Every continuous function(need not to be differentiable) has an antiderivative.**

I couldn't find any counter-example for the last two as well, makes them correct or I lack some knowledge please clear my doubts regarding these options.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @AndrewChin yes sir

Comment: @AndrewChin Oh yes D is the definition of FTC

Comment: As well as C:  $$f(x)=\frac d{dx}\int_a^xf(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: @AndrewChin Ok thanks what about A and B?

Comment: A - what about $f(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$?

Comment: $f(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x} \ \ \ ,$



$f'(x)=\sin \frac{1}{x}-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{1}{x},\ \ \ \ $

limit doesn't exist at $x=0$ .Option $A$ is incorrect too its not true always .Right?

Comment: C is wrong, every function (on an interval) that is the derivative of some other function satisfies the intermediate value property, but it is easy to write down functions that don't have this property. (For FTC you need continuity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard example for (A) is
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x) & x\ne0 \\[6px] 0 & x=0 \end{cases}
$$
The function is obviously differentiable for $x\ne0$, with
$$
f'(x)=2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}
$$
It is also differentiable at $0$, because
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}h\sin\frac{1}{h}=0
$$
However the derivative is not continuous at $0$.

Your example for (B) is incorrect, because your function has one-sided derivatives at $0$. A correct example would be $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$.

For (C) one can consider [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), according to which, if a function is differentiable over an interval, its derivative satisfies the intermediate value property. A function that doesn't satisfy this property cannot be a derivative. Example: the sign function.

For (D), every function that is *continuous over an interval* has an antiderivative. This is precisely the so-called “fundamental theorem of calculus”.